# Android popupmenu position

Tags: android, popupmenu

I am trying make an android app where clicking a button raises a `popupmenu`. The `popupmenu` is being generated but not at the correct position. The code is as follows:

*menu.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
    android:id="@+id/genderMale"
    android:title="Male"
/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/genderFemale"
    android:title="Female"
/>
</group>
</menu>
```

The function to execute the popup is as follows:

```
public void showGenderPopup(View v)
{
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.gender_popup, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

Here the `popupmenu` is being created just below the `textview` when I am clicking it. I want it to be generated at the centre of the screen.

How to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from docs says :

> A PopupMenu displays a Menu in a modal popup window anchored to a View. The popup will appear below the anchor view if there is room, or above it if there is not. If the IME is visible the popup will not overlap it until it is touched. Touching outside of the popup will dismiss it.

As I may guess, that "View v"

```
public void showGenderPopup(View v)
```

is the TextView you are clicking, which is bound to the method when it is clicked, meaning the PopupMenu will show right below the TextView.

Wouldn't you achieve your goal with a Dialog? For a custom AlertDialog you just need to use method

```
setView(View v)
```

of the AlertDialog.Builder , before creating the Dialog itself.

For your custom View you either follow two ways:

XML: 
Create your XML layout file and then using an inflater to apply the XML Layout over a View customView object. (layout file is called customDialog.xml as an example)

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customDialog, null);    

RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.customDialogRadioButton);
radioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { .. });
```

DYNAMICALLY :

I'll use LinearLayout as example.

```
LinearLayout customView = new LinearLayout(context);

RadioButton radioBtn = new RadioButton(context); 
radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { .. });

customView.addView(radioBtn);
```

To create the dialog you then use this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
b.setMessage("Example");

// set dialog's parameters from the builder

b.setView(customView);

Dialog d = b.create();
d.show();
```

Comment: Thing is I am also activating groups on the menu so as to get radio buttons. Don't think I can do that with the `AlertDialog` since it'll give me the choice of buttons and I o not want to use them. 

However, if it does manage to give me radio buttons I'll use it. Will google it ASAP.

Comment: Remember that you can always set a custom View to use inside a Dialog.

I myself have used a Dialog with 4 radioButtons, creating myself an easy-usable SQLite tool to debug on my DB right on the app.

You have to create an instance of a custom View where you add the radioButtons you need. Once you are done, just use

b.setView(customView);

just like described in the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(android.view.View)

Comment: Okay. So for defining a `popupmenu`, I have defined a custom menu For the view, I will have to define a new xml file in the layout files and then use it? Or some other way?

Comment: You can either follow the XML way, creating it and then using an inflater to apply the XML Layout over a View customView; object.

`LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customDialog, null);

b.setView(customView);`

Or you can create it dynamically. I'll use LinearLayout as example.

`LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
RadioButton radioBtn = new RadioButton(context);
linearLayout.addView(radioBtn);`

Comment: Could you add this to your answer for better readability. It would also improve the quality f your answer I guess.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. I define the `linear layout` and add the `radio buttons` and then make the `alert dialog` and show it. But then how do I add it to the `layout inflater`? Also, how do I ensure that only one `radio button` can be clicked at once?

Comment: LayoutInflater is used to make the system read a XML layout file and apply it to a view. If you use the dynamical way, you have no use at all for it.

For second question: you don't bind a onClickListener to the LinearLayout, but to the RadioButtons you need. If you added the listener to the layout, you'd just have 1 event, for the whole dialog view. Adding a clickListener to each radioButton, you ensure each of them behaves independently

Comment: for exiting the dialog you have different choice. You can add positive, neutral and/or negative buttons of the dialog (methods use those names, so check for them). As the buttons they are, you can bind clickListeners to them(beware the interface that implements them is different, so you'd need to specify that it is a
`DialogInterface.OnClickListener` kind of listener)

You can even set a listener to the dialog's cancel event(touching outside the dialog can dismiss it, this listener gives you a callback event), or even disable the cancel on touch outside.

Answer (score 28):

```
  PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v,Gravity.CENTER);
```

use above code. Gravity have many options like center/left/right check the documentation ocne

Comment: Does not work. Maybe because the view here is the TextView maybe and not the complete screen. That's my conclusion, don't know how correct I am tough but that is why I think it does not work.

Comment: put text view width match_parent and then try once.

Comment: Tried. No change whatsoever :/

Comment: Sorry dude, its like a 300 line code so don't really want to do that. Bear with me please?