# PopupMenu is not positioned properly inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

I'm making an Android app to load data into a RecyclerView with an ImageView inside as the overflow button. When users click it, a PopupMenu is displayed with options to choose. I had managed to show it but the position does not seem right. Please look at the screenshots.

[image]

Only the first two items seem OK. Here are the source code:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);
    final Menu menu = popupMenu.getMenu();

    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_action, menu);
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(onMenuItemClickListener);

    switch (Global.listMode) {
      case Global.LIST_STYLE_NORMAL: {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete).setVisible(false);
        break;
      }
      case Global.LIST_STYLE_FAVORITE: {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_add_to_favorite).setVisible(false);
        break;
      }
      case Global.LIST_STYLE_WATCH_LIST: {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_add_to_watch_list).setVisible(false);
        break;
      }
      case Global.LIST_STYLE_DOWNLOAD: {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_download).setVisible(false);
        break;
      }
    }

    itemPosition = (int) view.getTag(R.id.tag_item_position);
    popupMenu.show();
  }
});
```

Can you guys point me out the issue, I had took hours for searching but still found nothing up now.

P/S: The clicked button is marked with red circle.

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: This is something I'm working on as well for an application, is any of your code for this posted in a public forum like github? I'm trying to make the menu items have sections to them (IE a picture on the left, name in the middle, description on the right) but am having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Luckily, I've just found the way to solve the problem:

- Use `android.widget.PopupMenu` not `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu`
- Replace `final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);` with `final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, v);`

Honestly, I don't know why, just try it and voila!

Comment: `PopupMenu`'s documentation says "Used to write apps that run on platforms prior to Android 3.0. When running on Android 3.0 or above, this implementation is still used; it does not try to switch to the framework's implementation."

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. When I opened the popup menu using the app compat version it would scroll the recycler view!

Comment: Thanks. You saved my life!
I'm implement a PopupMenu using V7 (not native) in a RecyclerView and i can't show PopupMenu because error "You must supply a layout_height attribute.". I had try many ways to fix it, but do not. I change v7 to Native (android.widget.PopupMenu) ==> It's worked! Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, save my time.
after 2 years still you are right

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure but seems that a similar problem is duscussed 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089851/android-popupmenu-position)  and it already has an accepted answer. Hope it will help you with your problem. Just stumbled upon your question and saw the topic discussed in the link and thought maybe it might be helpful for you too.